# Following Google's tutorial, getting errors about ViewHolder not being able to hold a View, wants a TextView instead

Tags: android

So, as this is official documentation, I bet I'm doing something wrong somewhere but I can't understand how this is supposed to work.

Take a look at the example code of "Creating Lists and Cards": https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

In the source code of the MyAdapter class, the following lines can be found:

```
// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ...
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

As we can see in the ViewHolder class, a ViewHolder constructer is defined as taking a TextView as an argument. Towards the end of the code they're creating a ViewHolder holding v but as v is a View... how is this supposed to work? I get the following error

```
android.widget.ViewHolder(TextView) in ViewHolder cannot be applied to android.view.View
```

Casting the View to a TextView causes the app to crash.

What am I missing here? I am pretty new to Android so I figure it's something really basic, I apologize if it's a stupid question but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: you have to cast it. `inflate` will only return you a View, but you need a TextView. But that also means that the root of your my_text_view.xml layout needs to be a TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this

```
TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
```

The Error you're getting above is because you're not casting the view to TextView.

Also not the `my_text_view` - needs to TextView as it root element.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I didn't have TextView as the root element :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to case the view to a TextView. It would look something like this.

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
// create a new view
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                       .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
// set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
...
ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((TextView)v);
return vh;
}
```